# How to change the text in the revision log message?

Tags: 7

I would like to change the bottom text, "Provide an explanation of the changes you are making. This will help other authors understand your motivations.", in the revision log message section.  See attached screenshot.

[image]

How should I go about changing the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code in a custom module or in your theme's template.php:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_CONTENTTYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['revision_information']['log']['#description'] = t('Your new instructions.');
}
```

*Note:* replace `YOURMODULE` with your module/theme name and `CONTENTTYPE` with machine name of the content type you want to change.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will write my own module as to only affect the particular content types.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use the String Overrides module:

http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides

One of the major advantage is that you don't have to code anything and you will access to change the wording at any time thru the admin interface.

Comment: Very cool!  Unfortunately I need it to override certain content types, and not the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of node_form_alter we can alter the revision text by using form_alter also.

Ex:

```
function your_custom_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {  
    if($form_id == "custom_node_form") {
       $form['revision_information']['log']['#description'] = t('Your new instructions.');
    }   
}
```